# Laravel can't run test from a package

Tags: php, laravel

I have a package and I'm trying to setup testing, what I'm trying is to use the `Tests\TestCase` from my root laravel project, in which this package lives (in the vendor/package folder)

```php
<?php

namespace MyName\MyPackage\Tests\Unit;

use \Tests\TestCase;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
   //
}
```

I also updated my package's composer json to include the Tests folder in my autoloading

```php
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Codedor\\FilterForm\\Tests\\": "tests"
    }
},
```

After that I ran `composer dump-autoload`

But I get an error that it can't find the TestCase

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Tests\TestCase' not found in /Users/miguel/Code/project/vendor/myname/mypackage/tests/Unit/MyTest.php:9

Comment: did you run `composer install`, right?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you